# Hide mode-line for minimap buffers

Tags: mode-line

I know that I can hide the modebar for the current buffer using

<kbd>M</kbd> - <kbd>:</kbd> `(setq mode-line-format nil)`

However, I'd like to hide the mode-line for the 'MINIMAP' buffer created by the [`minimap` package](http://www.emacswiki.org/MiniMap), which is never the "current" buffer since as soon as you click anywhere on the minimap, the cursor is automatically moved to the original buffer. So the previous method does not work in this case.

The perfect solution would be to put something into my `.emacs` file so that every time I open a minimap the mode-line is automatically hidden from the buffer. Is it possible?

Comment: This does not answer the question (does not allow disabling the mode line depending on the buffer name), but for your particular use case I would try `(add-hook 'minimap-sb-mode-hook (lambda () (setq mode-line-format nil)))`. `minimap-sb-mode` is the minor mode used by MINIMAP sidebars.

Comment: @Constantine Thank you, as far as I am concerned this counts as an answer. The buffer name was just an approach I thought could be used to solve the problem, but your approach works fine too. So please feel free to turn you comment into an answer if you wish.

Comment: +1 for promoting @Constantine's comment to the answer. This also seems like a reasonable default behavior for `minimap` -- perhaps you could raise it as an issue or pull-request on Github?

Comment: @glucas will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable the mode line in Minimap sidebars, add a hook to `minimap-sb-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'minimap-sb-mode-hook (lambda () (setq mode-line-format nil)))
```

Comment: You should never advice core functions like `display-buffer`.  That's asking for trouble.  It's better to customize `display-buffer-alist`.

Comment: @lunaryorn: Good point. I'll remove that part from the answer.

Comment: Just in case someone needs this too. I am running Version: 20150108.1615 and the hook is different: `(add-hook 'minimap-mode-hook (lambda () (setq mode-line-format nil)))`